# Expand "hierarchical" system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation, simplifying-expressions

I have a system for equations that is structured hierarchically:
- Level 0: these are base variables that I can measure from a process (e.g. a,b,c)
- Level 1: these are variables derived from Level 0 variables (e.g. d=a+b, e=b*c)

- Level 2: these are variables derived from Level 1 variables (e.g. f=d*e)

For all Levels >0 I have only expressions that use variables from one level below, but I want to express those in terms of Level 0 variables.
In this case, I want to give Mathematica the expressions for a,b,c,d,e,f in the above form and have it show me that f=d*e=abc+b²c.

Thank you so much for any help
- a Mathematica beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I missed the point, but if you just copy and paste your expressions (and insert spaces to give multiplication) you get:

```
d = a + b;
e = b c;
f = d e
```

which gives you `b (a + b) c`, which is equivalent to your given `f`. Is this all you were asking?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are looking for the list of replacements that need to be made going down to level 0 instead of just showing the level 0 results. Are you looking for something like this?

```
assignments[d] = a + b;
assignments[e] = b c;
assignments[f] = d e;
assignments[x_] := x;

FixedPointList[Map[assignments, #, {-1}] &, {f}][[;; -2, 1]]
```

> `{f, d e, b (a + b) c}`

Comment: It really was that easy, thank you! I thought I had to keep everything in the format d[a_,b_]:=a+b